# Solution of equation

Tags: functions, quadratics

If $f(x) = x^2 - 2ax + a(a+1)$ , $f:[ a, \infty] \to [a,\infty]$ . If one of the solution of the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is $5049$ , then what may be the other solution ?

My WORK:

I found the inverse, but when I equate them , it is very difficult to solve . Please help me with some method to solve it.

Comment: Well, one of the solutions is always $a$, since $f(a)=a$ meaning that $f^{-1}(a)=a$...

Comment: I am not able to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $t = f^{-1}(x)$, you can write this as $f(f(t)) = t$, and this becomes
$$ (t-a)^4 = t-a$$
So either $t=a$, $x = a$, or $(t-a)^3 = 1$, $t = a + 1$, $x = a+1$.
Thus either $a = 5049$ and the other solution is $a+1=5050$, or $a+1 = 5049$ and the other solution is $a = 5048$.

Comment: How to get f(f(t))

Comment: $f(t) = (t-a)^2 + a$ so $f(f(t)) = ((t-a)^2+a - a)^2 + a = (t-a)^4 + a$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of equating the function and its inverse directly is perfectly alright.

$f(x) = x^2 - 2ax + a^2 + a$
or  $f(x) = (x-a)^2 + a$
or  $f(x) - a = (x-a)^2$
$x = a \pm \sqrt{f(x) - a}$

Here the negative sign is rejected as $x \in [a,\infty]$

So, we have $f^{-1}(x) = a + \sqrt{x - a}$

Now, $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$
$(x-a)^2 + a = a + \sqrt{x-a}$
$(x-a)^2 = \sqrt{x-a}$

$(x - a) ^ {\frac{1}{2}} ((x - a) ^ {\frac{3}{2}} - 1) = 0$

Therefore,
$x - a = 0$ or $(x - a)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 1$
$x = a$, or  $x = a + 1$